# How to require frequently used modules in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, webdriver, require

I am new to node.js. I am using node.js with selenium to automate UI tests. I require few  node modules such as fs,request,webdriver,assert etc. Do I have to require those module in every test i create? Is there a way to require all module with just one command?

Comment: You could write a module yourself that encompasses all of these other modules.

Comment: I tried this but it didnt work. I put all my modules under a  module.export file then tried to require that module but it doesnt return any module contained within it .     module.exports= {coremodules:{ 
assert: require('chai').assert,
xpath:require('xpath'),
webdriver: require('selenium-webdriver'),
By:require('selenium-webdriver').By,
until: require('selenium-webdriver').until }

Comment: I had to add those modules under a function and it worked. thanks

Comment: Cool.  Might want to include an answer for others to see and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

this worked

```js
module.exports =  {
coremodules: function coremodules (){
remote = require('selenium-webdriver/remote'),
assert= require('chai').assert,
xpath= require('xpath'),
action=require('selenium-webdriver').actionsequence,
webdriver= require('selenium-webdriver'),
By=require('selenium-webdriver').By


}
  }
```

then require that module